# macOS ptrace PT_GETREGS doesn't seem to exist

Tags: c, macos, macos-catalina

I want to try to get register values of a process using `ptrace`. It seems like most implementations of `ptrace` have some sort of `PTRACE_GETREGS` option for returning a `struct user_regs_struct`.

But after looking at the [macOS documentation for ptrace](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/ptrace.2.html) I'm a bit confused because there is no option for `PT_GETREGS` listed as an option for the `request` parameter. But at the bottom under "ERRORS", the documentation says:

> ```
>  [EINVAL]
>        oo   PT_GETREGS, PT_SETREGS, PT_GETFPREGS, or PT_SETFPREGS was
>            attempted on a process with no valid register set.  (This is
>            normally true only of system processes.)
> ```

Which seems to imply that `PT_GETREGS` exists. I've tried to use it but I get

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'PT_GETREGS'
```

Does `PT_GETREGS` actually exist in macOS ptrace?

Comment: It looks like it doesn't.  They probably just missed removing that reference from the man page.  According to https://www.spaceflint.com/?p=150 it looks like you're supposed to use `thread_get_state` instead.

Comment: http://uninformed.org/index.cgi?v=4&a=3&p=14 looks useful too.